# Why isn't my biblatex language changing when passing the language on my document class and/or explicitly to biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, abnt, abntex2

If I build the following document, its language it set to `brazil`:

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{koma-scrguien,
    author = {Markus Kohm},
    edition = {2017-04-13},
    howpublished = {\url{http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/.../scrguien.pdf}},
    publisher = {Online Material; \url{https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script}},
    title = {The Guide KOMA -Script},
    urlaccessdate = {2017-08-28},
    year = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents*}

% \PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english,spanish,french}{babel}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\selectlanguage{english}

\usepackage[
style=abnt,repeatfields=true,backend=biber,backref=true,language=english]{biblatex}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citing \cite{koma-scrguien}. \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, its language should be set to `english` because:

1. On my `\documentclass`, I pass `english` as the last class option
2. And I pass `english` as the `biblatex` `\usagepackage` option

The only way to set the document language to english is uncommenting the line `\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english,spanish,french}{babel}`

[image]

Why isn't the document language changing to English by passing the `english` language as the last option to `\documentclass`?

Comment: `abntex2` seems to reset the language in at the beginning of the document regardless of the global `english` option. Try adding `\today` after `\begin{document}` and observe that the date comes out Brazilian. `biblatex`'s `language` option only does what you expect it to do if you also set `autolang=other,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put `\selectlanguage{english}` after `\begin{document}` and it worked.

```
\documentclass[english]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{koma-scrguien,
    author = {Markus Kohm},
    edition = {2017-04-13},
    howpublished = {\url{http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/.../scrguien.pdf}},
    publisher = {Online Material; \url{https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script}},
    title = {The Guide KOMA -Script},
    urlaccessdate = {2017-08-28},
    year = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[
style=abnt,repeatfields=true,backend=biber,backref=true,language=english]{biblatex}
%\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
Citing \cite{koma-scrguien}. \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, what did you do here? Can you add some explanation?

Comment: @user, see my updated answer.